# MySQL Cant connect.. details correct

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

Forgive me if this is a dumb question but this is really frustrating.

Im having issues trying to connect to my MySQL database. The details are correct as i can login via phpmyadmin and terminal, the database was created with the user whose details i used in this script but i keep getting 'Cannot connect to database' Its been bugging me and frustrating me for hours now lol.

```
<?php  
$host = "localhost"; 
$username = "root";  
$pass = "password";  
$name = "database"; 

$connect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);

if ($connect){
    $select = mysqli_select_db($name);
    if ($select){
        echo "Connected successfully.";
    } else {
        echo "Could not connect to database";
    }
} else {
    echo "Could not connect to MySQL";
}

?>
```

The script this is for is working but its not progressing because it cant insert the information to the database to continue with the rest of the script.

I have looked at other posts on here and none of the solutions provided worked, so i am posting this.

Please help!

Comment: Does it work from outside of the script (if you do it manually?)

Comment: No, i still get 'Cannot connect to database'

Comment: If you're actually using `$name = "database";` and your DB is indeed called `database`, I suggest you change it to something else. [`database` is a reserved word.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: @PrivateMufasa then it seems like the credentials you have are wrong

Comment: It is, I called t database for posting it here. Same as password is not password.

Comment: You say that it "IS" called `database` - rename it to `database1` for example and try it again, including the DB itself.

Comment: @ExplosionPills but I can login, edit, add and drop tables and information via phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry, ipad autocorrect. It's not called database.

Comment: have you tried using 2 parameters in `mysqli_select_db` like `mysqli_select_db($connect,$name);` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Comment: @Miguelo thank you, I did try it like that but I had it the wrong way around. Things you do when your frustrated!

Comment: Aaahhh, another Happy Ending!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing a parameter in `mysqli_select_db` it takes 2 parameters like this `mysqli_select_db($connect,$name);`

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Answer (score -2):

it can't work because it's not correct drop the little (i) of mysqli_connect
and make sure details are correct and you have a database named "database"
and try again 
                                googluck